# how to delete all files with a path pattern

Tags: linux, find, rm

I have a backup location, which uses hardlinks to store existing or changed files. The location of these backups mimick the linux file system with a date part in it.

For example I have files

```
/backup/servername/2012-06-26T00.43.01/www.website.com/file1.html
/backup/servername/2012-06-26T06.43.01/www.website.com/file1.html
/backup/servername/2012-06-26T06.43.01/www.website.com/file2.html
/backup/servername/2012-06-26T12.43.01/www.website.com/file1.html
/backup/servername/2012-06-26T12.43.01/www.website.com/file2.html
```

How can I find all files which have www.website.com in them, so I can delete them

I have this command combination to delete files I can find with find, but I can't figure out how to find these files.

```
find . -name 'filename.*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What happens if you just run the find without piping its result to xargs? Did you specify the correct path, ie. are the files located in a subdir relative to your current working directory? If not, replace `.` with the correct path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're being a little loose with your terminology, so it's a kind of tough to understand what exactly you want.  However, if I understood you correctly, you want to delete all the files *within* a directory called `www.website.com`:

```
find . -wholename '*/www.website.com/*.html' -delete
```

Comment: that's true about my answer I didn't test any of those. +1

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you right you can use smth like this: `find  /backup/servername/2012-06-26T12.43.01/www.website.com/ -iname '*file*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm`

Comment: That won't find *all* of the files the OP is looking for.  It will only find the files in the `2012-06-26T12.43.01` directory.